# How to resolve package conflict in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use an external package for generating a PDF document. I have used [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) but when I import the below packages, I get en error

> The name 'StatelessWidget' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' and 'package:pdf/widgets.dart'.

Error screen shot is attached.

Import statements:

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
```

Error:

[image]

Can anyone help me in this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Classes defined in `package:pdf` are conflicting with those defined in `package:flutter`. Dart allows you to import a package under a namespace to avoid such conflicts.

Change your second import statement to:

```dart
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pdf;
```

then you can access anything defined in the package with `pdf.` before it:

```dart
pdf.SomeWidgetName
```

Answer (score 4):

How about just hiding `StatelessWidget` from the imported library? Try using the `hide` keyword to resolve the conflict:

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' hide StatelessWidget;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the package that was made specifically for dart. This package may include functions already defined in flutter causing dart to have 2 definitions of the same function. Try [this for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

Answer (score -1):

you need the dart: prefix in your imports it should work as

```
import 'dart:pdf';
```

no need to for anything else.

Comment: I have imported like `import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';`

Comment: @FredGrott as you can see in [this](https://i.imgur.com/2EJqCRf.png) image, `dart:pdf` does **not** exist.